# a site built with Jekyll at a project repository on GitHub pages(not my user repository) works locally but redirect to my post not correct when online

Tags: web, jekyll

I am new to Jekyll, I built [this](http://www.erichliu.site/test/reading/) blog with Jekyll at a project repository on GitHub pages(not my user repository and named 'test'), it works locally but redirect not correct.

I linked to this blog site from my personal website(which is at my user repository and with a CNAME file). But when I click my post in blog site, it can not display although it works well locally.

As you can see, my blog's url is `http://www.erichliu.site/test/reading/`,
I find that when I insert 'test' into a wrong jumped url for example: `http://www.erichliu.site/sequnetial-data-learning/` to `http://www.erichliu.site/test/sequnetial-data-learning/` then it can be visited.

In `_config.yml` file, I set

```
url: http://Erichliu00.github.io
baseurl: /test
permalink: /:title/
```

How can I fix this problem? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Remlve url key from _config.yml and try again.

Comment: Thank you, it seems not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a base URL, then use the relative URL filter so that Jekyll prepends the `baseurl` value to your URLs.

For example, if your `baseurl` is set to `test`, this:

```
<a href="{{ "hello" | relative_url }}">
```

Will become:

```
/test/hello
```

See https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/ for more information (it's the first filter in the list).

Comment: Sorry I am new to Jekyll... After editing a line to `<a href="{{ post.url  | relative_url }}" style="color: #666;">{{ post.title }}</a>`  the blog site can not visit.

Comment: It seems that it was due to DNS cache! Now it works after I modifying as above, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you generate the blog posts links you are missing `base_url`.

Add `base_url` when generating links:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
<a href="{{post.url | prepend: site.baseurl}}">{{post.title}}</a>
{% endfor%}
```

This way you will generate flexible urls using the base_url configuration instead of hardcoding this value.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem as the way @jpvillaisaza suggested, and I think your solution also targets my problem. It should also works me. Thank you.